# Ansible handlers and shell module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook with the following task and handler section (just a snippet):

```
  tasks:
    - name: 'Run legacy script and power off'
      debug: msg="Preparing for reboot"
      notify: Legacy sysprep

  handlers:
    - name: Enable Service1
      service: name=service1 enabled=yes state=restarted

    - name: Legacy sysprep
      shell: /var/scripts/prep-reboot.sh
```

When I run the playbook, I see the debug message for the task that calls the `Legacy sysprep` handler, and I see the `Enable Service1` handler executed, but the `Legacy sysprep` handler isn't called (it doesn't show up in the playbook output, nor does it run on the system) and the servers are not rebooted (part of the script).

Yes, I plan to migrate the prep-reboot.sh script to an Ansible playbook, but I was surprised that apparently the `shell` module doesn't seem to work?  Or is there an error I've overlooked?  Running with `-vvv` doesn't report anything unexpected.

Ansible and Ansible-playbook version 2.1.1.0 running on RHEL 6.8.

Comment: There is no way for any of the handlers to run in the example you have given, because `debug` will return `ok` status. That said, the question is incomprehensible. Please provide a **verifiable** example.

Comment: @techraf - Thanks for the hint, I've added the "changed_when: true" to the play and now the handler triggers.  See the answer I've posted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you, @techraf you got me pointed in the right direction.  I ended up adding the `changed_when: true` to the debug line and that forces that play to register a change which then triggers the appropriate handler.

Here is my actual test playbook for reference:

```
---
- name: Testing forced handler
  hosts: testsys_only
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: 'Run legacy script and power off'
      debug: msg="Preparing for reboot"
      changed_when: true
      notify: Legacy sysprep

  handlers:
    - name: Enable Service1
      service: name=service1 enabled=yes state=restarted

    - name: Legacy sysprep
      shell: /var/scripts/prep-reboot.sh
```

Comment: within handlers->shell can be some command as well, like program configuration reload: `rkhunter --propupd`. However, it is probably obvious.